# How to whitelist all shareable apps in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an `iOS` application, In This application I want to share content with social media Using `**UIActivityViewController**` but I want to restrict it to some apps only.

I want to whitelist/exclude all the shareable options e.g. if I want only `Pinterest` and `Facebook` then in the list these 2 options should only be there. I know there is an option to exclude all unwanted options but it is not feasible. Currently I am doing like this.

```
UIActivityViewController *ActivityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:<#postItems>                                        applicationActivities:Acts];

[ActivityView setExcludedActivityTypes:
 @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
   UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
   UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]];
```

Is it possible to whitelist? if yes how can I achieve it?

Hope the question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take the complete list of `UIActivity` values and remove the items you want to share.  Put this code in a method of its own, taking the whitelist as a parameter.

```
static NSArray *activities = @[ ... list of all activities here ... ];

- (NSArray *)whitelist:(NSArray *)whitelist
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableActivities = [activities mutableCopy];
    [mutableActivities removeObjectsInArray:whitelist];

    return [mutableActivities copy];
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the code for overall workflow and how to identify pinterest like apps which do not have inbuilt UIActivity.